# Connect web/mobile devices using Rest Api?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, authentication

I am developing a REST API using Java Spring Boot framework. Purpose of this API is to connect mobile and web applications so they can work together.

My question is, what are the best practices to develop login functions or the login process. Shall I generate a token or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the best practices as described in OWASP, [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet).

Most APIs nowadays use token based security. Here are a few guidelines:

- You need one service (which is itself public) that authenticates the user.

  - In order to authenticate the user, it might use a username and a password, and/or other means.
  - As the result of authenticating the user, this service returns an authorization token.
  - Your backend should keep track of issued tokens.
  - Each token will have an expiration time.
- Every time the client uses an API, it should send along the token. Usually, the token is sent as an HTTP header.
- Every service in the API should validate the token before anything else. If the token is invalid, it should return an appropiate HTTP code.

**All communications should be sent over SSL.**

OAuth and OAuth2 are two very well known protocols for this very goal. OAuth is a little more complicated than OAuth2.

This is a very high level description, not technically deep, but it should get you started.